# Symfony2 request event

Tags: events, request, symfony

I am trying to execute a task on every request with Symfony2, so far I have no idea how to achieve this. My idea is simple - I need to check a session variable on authenticated user on every request this user makes. The main reason to do this is to provide functionality that is available for certain periods of time. Can you point me into the right direction ? Or does anyone have better idea for such kind of functionality ? Thanks.

Comment: What will be the end result of your checking? Allowing access if the variable is present and denying if not?

Comment: @Problematic - Well yes, kind of. Setting variable to true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hook into [kernel.request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-request-event) event. See [example implementation here](http://www.fractalizer.ru/frpost_658/symfony2-how-redirect-user-to-a-previous-page-correctly/), I've just blogged about it. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot :) it should work this way, well with some changed but it should do the trick.

Comment: @zlat If you will find any way to improve this thing, ping me please ;)

Comment: This is a link only answer, and as such is susceptible to link rot.. Could you please include the contents of the link into the post?